# How can I encrypt my dotenv variables when running `npm run build`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, dotenv

I am building a firebase application using React v17.0.2 that uses dotenv v8.2.0 to populate the firebaseConfig object.

When I run `npm run build` it bundles the scripts and puts it in the build folder (obviously) but I noticed that when I view the javascript file that was bundled in the build I can see all the dotenv values. This is a huge security risk as it contains the api key for the firebase app.

For clarity this is what the firebaseConfig variable looks like

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGE_SENDING_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID
};
```

Is there a way to hide or encrypt these values?

Comment: There isn't any risk involved (as long as you have security rules setup correctly). Checkout: [Is it safe to expose Firebase apiKey to the public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public)

Comment: No, there isn't. Because if you hid or encrypted them, you'd also have to ship the code to unhide or decrypt them to the client. The whole point of the `REACT_APP_` prefix is that you _don't_ use it for things that shouldn't be exposed to the client.

Comment: I am confused on your point @jonrsharpe, how else am I supposed to get the variables into the firebaseConfig object?